# How do I change the Screenshots folder?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-screenshot

I downloaded *dconf* and set `/org/gnome/gnome-screenshot/auto-save-directory` to the custom value `/home/lohroc/Pictures/Screenshots`. But, pressing <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> still saves the picture to the `Pictures` folder.

Comment: Does this extension help? https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1179/screenshot-locations/

Comment: What program is being used to do the screen captures? How was the app installed? Was it a SNAP package?

Comment: does the folder exist?

Comment: I would rather not install an extension just for that, it would be the default Ubuntu screenshot program gnome-screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend installing falmeshot.
Install `sudo apt install flameshot`.
After installation, attach the `/usr/bin/flameshot gui` command to the `Print` keyboard.